# How to specifically send either a chat message to all players or only allies?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings, age-of-empires-ii-hd

With the definitive edition I want to play more of this old game.
One problem I've always had is how to chat only to allies or everyone.
It's unclear to me where the default Enter chat goes to, it seems everyone.
How can this be specified?

Comment: Seems like you already asked this question two years ago :). Is it exactly the same?

Comment: @Mixxiphoid Forgot about that and could not find that question on Arcade. Even with hindsight, it's hard to find, you have to get the game tag exactly right and I didn't get it as a suggestion when asking the question. For those two years I played almost no AoE.

Comment: the search on stackexchange is not the best, I saw the question and remembered me answering it before, that's how I found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "trumpet" icon at the top of the screen to open the chat dialog. There you can use the check marks to select the players your message shall be shown to.

See the icon pointed out by the red arrow in the top right corner:

[image]

[image]

Alternatively, you can use various characters when typing a message to select a group of recipients:

- Send message to enemies: `#`
- Send message to allies: `;`
- Send message to everyone regardless of the team: `*`

Example use:

```
#Your villager is ours now! Wololo!
```